# Совет по разработке Веб-приложения

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Есть таблица (сделанная в html), есть элемент который я перемещаю по странице с помощью мыши и JavaScipt-а. 
    Нужно что-бы в тот момент когда я отпускаю элемент (отжимаю кнопку мыши) происходило выравнивание его в ячейке таблицы которая под ним.
    У меня есть объект (картинка 50х50 и ячейки 50х50),соответственно вот что я придумал:

> заранее знать координаты каждой
> ячейки, и при каждом отпуске проверять
>
> - если элемент находиться между х>=100 и х<=200  также y>=100 и y<=200
>   тогда
> - присваиваю Top & Left объекта координатам центра ячейки (они уже
>   заранее известны)

вроде бы и не плохо, но очень много текста и как-то по дикому)

Может у вас есть варианты ?
Спасибо.

P.s Объекты(картинки) создаются динамически.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задайте класс ячейкам таблице, сделайте запрос jquery по классу и сравнивайте с position:

```
var prev;
$('.cell_type').each(function(){ if(x>=prev && x <= $(this).position().top)
... 
  prev = $(this).position().top;
 });
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду значить JQuery учить. просто я такое делал уже, только через чистый JS не мог узнать координаты определенной ячейки, возвращало то пустоту то undefined. Не знал что с JQuery можно координату каждой ячейки.